# How to stop an ValueAnimator without Listener.onAnimationEnd called

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

I add an `AnimatorListenerAdapter` into an `ValueAnimator`, but i need to stop the `ValueAnimator` while it's running sometime.

I tried `ValueAnimator.cancel()` or `ValueAnimator.stop()`, they both can stop the animator, but the `AnimatorListenerAdapter.onAnimationEnd()` called which is I don't want.

`ValueAnimator.pause()` works but it's only above api 19, so i can't use it;

Is there anyway else I can do this?

Comment: Why not use a `boolean` field somewhere to inform your `onAnimationEnd()` implementation "hey, don't do your normal processing"?

Comment: @CommonsWare This is the answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you post the answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `cancel()` or `stop()`, along with a `boolean` field somewhere. The `boolean` serves as a flag to tell `onAnimationEnd()` whether or not it should do its regular work. Default that `boolean` to `true`; flip it to `false` when you want to block normal animation-end processing.

Comment: Is there any documentation that suggests that this is the behavior of `onAnimationEnd()` ?

Comment: @toobsco42: I am uncertain what documentation you are seeking. I am describing an implementation of `onAnimationEnd()`, where it would use a `boolean` to determine whether it should do its normal work or not.

Comment: ValueAnimator.cancel(boolean) not found

Comment: @maXp: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#cancel()

Answer (score 17):

Under certain circumstances, the use of the flag may cause problems.

You should using removeListener before call cancel method:

```
animator.removeAllListeners(); // Or animator.removeListener(your listener);
animator.cancel();
```